# Where to put custom initialization code in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Let's say I've two services:

```
get('my_first_service')
get('my_second_service')
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$this->get('my_first_service')->doSomething($this->get('my_second_service'));
```

This is some initialization code that must be active everywhere in the project. As far as I see I have a few options (both services originates from the vendor-dir (haven't writtem them myself)):

1. Add the above code (with some modifications) in app.php and/or app_dev.php
2. Add the above code to every controller action
3. Create a service with the services as arguments and add the above code in the constructor

The first option seems a little bit "unusual" as I don't link editing the app.php file for something link this. The second option is too inefficient as I need to do this for dozens of actions. The third action seems better but I still need to call this service from somewhere in order to execute the constructor right?

I have the feeling I'm missing a possibility... there must be a better place for this kind of initialization code right?

Comment: If `my_first_service` is dependent on `my_second_service`, then you should configure the first service to have the second service injected in, by any of the necessary injection methods the DIC makes available.

Comment: If the problem is creating the instance automatically for each request, tag it as a [listener](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/dic_tags.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do execute your code before EVERY action, you can listen for the event kernel.controller.

Check [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) in the cookboook.

Your listener is a service so you can inject both of your services if needed.

Answer (score 1):

That looks very similar to [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection). You could add doSomething as a call, with my_second_service as a parameter. That way when you get the first_service, the method will be called automatically, with the correct parameter passed in, and saves you from an ugly hack.

I assume you are already defining the services in configuration.

Eg in YAML:

```
services:
   my_second_service:
       # ...
   my_first_service:
       class: MyFirstServiceClassName
       calls:
           - [ doSomething, [ @my_second_service ] ]
```

If doSomething is returning a different object that you need to use, then it sounds like a factory, which you can also configure. Read through [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The services are already defined since they are part of two 3rd party libraries installed via composer. The above code defines new services but what I really want is just setter injection in an existing service. Can I also do this via services.yml?

Comment: Yeh the answer above looks better in this case